# Error al obtener ruta relativa en python

Tags: python

Intento obtener la ruta relativa para abrir un documento txt mediante el siguiente código:

```
imports os

filePath = os.path.relpath('../ProyectoLenguajeInterprete/Test')

txt = open(filePath)
print "Content for: %r:" % filePath
print txt.read()
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "C:\Users\equipo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoLenguajeInterprete\src\proyectolenguajeinterprete.py", line 114, in <module>
>          txt = open(filePath)
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\ProyectoLenguajeInterprete\Test'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que tu ruta relativa apunta a un directorio inexistente.

Si la fuente se está interpretando en

```
"C:\Users\equipo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoLenguajeInterprete\src\proyectolenguajeinterprete.py"
```

Entonces la ruta `.. /` apunta a `src/`.
Asimismo la ruta `../../` apuntará a `src/ProyectoLenguajeInterprete`

Aquí podrías llamar directamente al archivo, definiendo `filePath = os.path.relpath('../../Test')` lo que resulta más elegante.

Si el ejercicio exige la cadena `ProyectoLenguajeInterprete` en la variable `filePath` entonces debes subir un nivel más en la ruta relativa:

```
filePath = os.path.relpath('../../../ProyectoLenguajeInterprete/Test')
```

Cuando uses rutas relativas, sobre todo cuando defines submodulos en una estructura de directorios recuerda que tú `CWD` donde anclas la ruta es el directorio donde se está interpretando la fuente de la rutina actual.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema puede ser que te falta la extensión del archivo si la tiene. En tu directorio `ProyectoLenguajeInterprete` debe existir un archivo, algo como `Test.txt` no `Test` simplemente:

```
filePath = '../ProyectoLenguajeInterprete/Test.txt'

txt = open(filePath)
print "Content for: %r:" % filePath
print txt.read()
txt.close()
```

Comment: Negativo, en el ambiente POSIX que el interpretador emula, un archivo es un archivo es un archivo, independientemente de su extensión.

Comment: @hlecuanda tienes razón en que no tiene importancia la extensión a la hora de manejar un archivo pero si a la hora de manejar la ruta dado que **la extensión, de tenerla, es parte del nombre del propio archivo**. Si un archivo se llama `Test.txt` y lo intentas abrir pasandole una ruta `.../Test` nunca va a encontrar el archivo porque ese nombre no existe. Por eso digo que puede ser una posibilidad. Claro que vendría muy bién que el OP añadiera la estructura de sus directorios para ver donde está `Test` con respecto al script para poder ayudarle mejor.

Comment: Es correcto, @FJSevilla . =) De hecho, la excepción que arroja el interpretador nos da luz sobre la estructura de directorios. De ahí mi deducción de que el archivo se encuentra dos niveles sobre CWD. Pero coincido contigo en que una especificación vale más que diez kilos de datos asumidos. =)

Comment: Pues si, tu respuesta es otra posibilidad que, viendo el nombre del directorio, puede ser lo que le pasa (está apuntando al directorio equivocado). Lo que está claro es que ese archivo no existe en la ruta que le pasa. Claro que sin saber la estructura de su proyecto estamos 'dando palos de ciego' XD. No obstante creo que o está cometiendo uno de los errores que mostramos en nuestras respuestas o los dos a la vez. La tercera posibilidad es que intentara crear el archivo si no existe sin especificar los modos `a` o `w`, pero dado que intenta leer su contenido no creo que sea el caso.